# check if schedule overlaps date first before inserting in SQL

Tags: php, sql

i want to check first in my database if two of the schedules would overlap. if the schedules overlap, it will return. else, the information will be inserted in the database. here is my code:

```
 <?php
include("../sql_connect.php");
session_start();
$user_id = $_SESSION['num'];
$event_id = $_GET['id'];
$event_start = $_POST['event_start'];


$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = $user_id";
$data = mysqli_query($sql,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
$first_name=$row['first_name'];
$last_name=$row['last_name'];


$query1 = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE $event_start >= 'event_start' and $event_start <= 'event_end' ";
$data1 = mysqli_query($sql,$query1);

echo "$query1";

if (!empty($data1)){
    echo "cannot pre reg"
}else {

//check if pre registered
$check_query = "SELECT * FROM record";
$check_data = mysqli_query($sql,$check_query);
$cnt = mysqli_num_rows($check_data);
$check_row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_data);
//echo $cnt;
//loop through records table

    //pre record query
$user_query = "INSERT INTO records VALUES ('',
                                                $event_id,
                                                $user_id,
                                                NOW())";

$user_data = mysqli_query($sql,$user_query);
$select_query = "SELECT * FROM record WHERE user_id = $user_id AND event_id = $event_id";
$select_data = mysqli_query($sql, $select_query);                                                   

$output = array();
while($select_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_data)){
    $output[] = $select_row;
}
}

echo json_encode($output);


}


?>
```

hoping for a feedback real soon!

Comment: `INSERT INTO records VALUES ('',$event_id,$user_id,NOW())` Whats This ????

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows`

Comment: You code is susceptible to SQL injection. There is a nice walk through here that should help you fix it. https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

use [`mysqli_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) instead of `empty`

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($data1) > 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with this. To name a few things.

1. No `isset()` or `empty()` check on `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` variables
2. Using `*` instead of individual columns
3. Using relative over absolute path
4. Not using prepared statements, as you are susceptible to SQL injection
5. Not an issue, but I'd suggest using OOP over procedural MySQLi
6. Insert is completely wrong

Here's what I'd do, based off of what I understand your code as. I might be be misinterpreting some parts.

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "../sql_connect.php";
session_start();


//Use isset() instead of empty() if you're anticipating falsy values
if(empty($_SESSION['num'])) { 
  exit(json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Session variable is empty']));
}
else if(empty($_GET['id'])) { 
  exit(json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'No id given']));
}
else if(empty($_POST['event_start'])) { 
  exit(json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'No event start given']));
}
else if(empty($_POST['event_end'])) { 
  exit(json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'No event end given']));
}

$user_id = $_SESSION['num'];
$event_id = $_GET['id'];
$event_start = $_POST['event_start'];
$event_start = $_POST['event_end'];

//Select columns individually, instead of * and use prepared statements
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$nameArr = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(!$nameArr) exit(json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'No rows']));
echo $nameArr['first_name'];
echo $nameArr['last_name'];
$stmt->close();


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event WHERE event_start <= ? AND event_end >= ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $event_start, $event_start);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($countPreregister);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

if($countPreregister === 0) {
  exit(json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'Cannot preregister']));
}

//**No idea what the purpose of this is, as values aren't used again**   

//check if pre registered
//$check_query = "SELECT * FROM record";
//$check_data = mysqli_query($sql,$check_query);
//$cnt = mysqli_num_rows($check_data);
//$check_row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_data);
//echo $cnt;
//loop through records table

//Column names need to be entered. No need for NOW() if your DB already does this
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO records (event_id, user_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $event_id, $user_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM record WHERE user_id = ? AND event_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $event_id);
$stmt->execute();
$output = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if(!$output) exit(json_encode(['status' => 0, 'msg' => 'No rows']));
$stmt->close();

exit(json_encode(['status' => 1, 'msg' => $output]));
```